# incompatibles types : list<object> cannot be converted to List<Usuario>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a error:

> incompatibles types : list < object> cannot be converted to list< usuario>

I don't why, i need your help

```
package com.dao;

import com.persistence.Usuario;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;


public class ImpLogin extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IfaceLogin{
    @Override
    public Usuario validaLogin(Usuario obj) {
        List<Usuario> list= getHibernateTemplate().find("from Usuario where login= ? and clave= ?",
                obj.getLogin(),obj.getClave());
        if(list.size()>0){
            return list.get(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: `getHibernateTemplate().find()` is returning a List<Object> instead of List<Usuario>

Comment: Maybe add a `Usuario` cast to your `List<Object>`

Answer (score 2):

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from Usuario where login= ? and clave= ?", obj.getLogin(),obj.getClave());
```

returns a list of objects. Thats why you get then error.

Answer (score 1):

This call

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from Usuario where login= ? and clave= ?",
            obj.getLogin(),obj.getClave());
```

Is returning:

```
List<Object>
```

You could cast the returned list to

```
List<Usuario>
```

Like so:

```
List<Usuario> list = (List<Usuario>) getHibernateTemplate().find("from Usuario where login= ? and clave= ?", obj.getLogin(),obj.getClave());
```

Comment: I have already done it, but I keep having the same error.

`List<Usuario> list = (List<Usuario>) getHibernateTemplate().find("from Usuario where login= ? and clave= ?", obj.getLogin(),obj.getClave());`

Comment: You can do this with 2 casts: `List<Usuario> list = (List<Usuario>) (Object) getHibernateTemplate().find("from Usuario where login= ? and clave= ?", obj.getLogin(),obj.getClave());`, but I wouldn't recommend it.